# "Carbon capture into fuel" - where does the energy come from?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, physical-chemistry

I recently found an article titled "Scientists find a way to convert Carbon Dioxide from air into fuel" ([here](http://interestingengineering.com/scientists-find-a-way-to-converts-carbon-dioxide-from-air-into-fuel/)), and my immediate reaction was "surely not - the energy balance would kill you right away". It seems, however, that this is a serious proposal, with a piece in [Phys.org](http://m.phys.org/news/2016-01-carbon-dioxide-captured-air-methanol.html) and a legitimate journal article,

> Conversion of CO<sub>2</sub> from Air into Methanol Using a Polyamine and a Homogeneous Ruthenium Catalyst. J. Kothandaraman et al. [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **138** (3), pp 778–781 (2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jacs.5b12354).

The InterestingEngineering and Phys.org pieces talk mostly about the new catalysts found by Kothandaraman and co-workers, and the journal article goes rather above my head - which I suspect is also the case for most of the general public.

So, in the interest of having someone somewhere make it clear that energy is always conserved and that miracle schemes always have their cost: **where does the energy come from in the carbon-capture scheme proposed by Kothandaraman et al.?** In what resources is that energy stored, how much energy do those resources have, and how would those be created?

Comment: I suspect most of the energy game is in the hydrogenation shown in the graphical abstract, and if I have time to make sure I'll write an answer, but I'd rather have something with a good budget of energies in terms of just how expensive it is to make those hydrogens, so I thought I'd leave the question open.

Comment: Ultimately that energy will come, as others have said, from renewal energy sources. Carbon capture with plants is inefficient, on the order of 0.1% to maybe around 1%. In comparison solar cells can convert sunlight with 15% efficiency (the thermodynamics limits is actually around 94% or so). This amounts to an area advantage of over an order of magnitude compared to a conventional biofuel scheme based on farming, with the additional advantage that solar cells do not need farmland, at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to how plants capture CO2 and form "fuels" (sugars) to feed themselves.  In the natural case, the energy comes from sunlight captured by the chlorophylls in the plant cells, and the chemical reaction is carried out by a group of enzymes (Photosystem I and Photosystem II).

A lot of scientists are trying to replicate this process industrially using artificial catalysts, and this seems to be what your source is talking about.  In this case, there are several possible sources for the energy.  The most common are sunlight or electricity - ultimately these chemical reactions are due to the transfer of electrons, and an applied electric potential can drive this.  This is what the sunlight approach does as well - an electron is excited by a photon, and ultimately this leads to the application of a potential that drives the reaction.

As far as how much energy is needed... well, you have to consider the whole picture to understand that.  There's another side to the process, and that is the conversion of water into oxygen gas (this is why plants release oxygen into the atmosphere!).  The potential difference across these two processes turns out to be +1.23 V - this assumes 100% thermodynamic efficiency.  Most real systems are significantly higher (+1.7 to +1.8 V) because some of the energy is lost as heat, and so a lot of current research is focused on lowering this gap to the ideal +1.23 V.

**EDIT:** I apologize, the +1.23 V is for the reduction of H+ to H2.  The reduction of CO2 to CH3OH is closer to +1.6 V.

Comment: The question is for this specific scheme. What is the energy source used here?

Comment: Reading the paper, it seems to be a combination of chemical energy stored in bonds that are changing, and thermal energy added by heating a solution containing the catalyst.  These are just laboratory conditions used to test the catalyst, though - if this ever made it to the application stage, either electricity or solar would be used as the energy source.

Comment: Exactly. So the question asks which chemical bonds have the energy, how much of it, and how you'd put it there.

Comment: It appears to primarily be in the amine N-H bonds, and it transfers to the methanol via proton-coupled electron transfer with the CO2 as an acceptor.  How much is there?  Typical N-H bond energies are 386 kJ/mol (http://www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/data/bond_energies_lengths.html), but this is for the ideal case and the actual amount will be slightly different.  As for how it got there, well, someone made the molecule, and the formation of the bond stored the energy there.

Comment: To follow up: this system is not magically producing fuel in violation of conservation of energy.  The N-H bond is consumed and is not regenerated.  In a production system, the energy would be continuously introduced either electrochemically or photochemically.